# Header above navbar appears on mobile scroll when it should be hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed content on mobile above a Bootstrap navbar. When scrolling down, the navbar is moved up 50px (the content above navbar is 50px height). Everything works great, but as soon as the address bar disappears in mobile, top content is shown again and I do not understand why. On desktop while resizing it is working good. How can I prevent this kind of action?

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="header-top-logo"><a href="/"><img src="assets/logo_reverse.svg" class="logo" alt="Superhoidjad"></a></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <a class="navbar-brand" class="pull-left" href="{{route('main.home')}}"><img src="assets/logo.svg" class="logo" alt="Superhoidjad"></a>
         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-item">
               {{--
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/login">Sisene</a></li>
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/signup/family">Registreeri&nbsp</a></li>
               --}}
               <li class="nav-item {{ Route::current()->getName() == 'main.about' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="{{route('main.about')}}">Meist</a></li>
               <li class="nav-item {{ Route::current()->getName() == 'main.articles.all' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="{{route('main.articles.all')}}">Artiklid</a></li>
               <li class="nav-btn{{ Route::current()->getName() == '' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#parent_signup" class="search-nanny">Saada kutse</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

My JS

```
//top logo scroll function
function logoScroll() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
        } else {
            $(".navbar").css("top", "50px");
        }
    });
}

//hide top logo on load
var wdwWidth = $(window).width();
if (wdwWidth <= 991) {
    $(".navbar").css("top", 50);
    logoScroll();
} else {
    $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try responding to the resize event as well.

```
$window.resize(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
        $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
    } else {
        $(".navbar").css("top", "50px");
    }
});
```

Comment: To be honest I had it, just did not want to write it. Thought it is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

how about changing your js to this:

```
//top logo scroll function
function logoScroll() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            $(".navbar").css("top", "0px");
            $("#header-top-logo").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $(".navbar").css("top", "50px");
            $("#header-top-logo").css("display", "block");
        }
     }
});
```

EDIT:

Try this (...maybe the .css functions should switch place I dunn really understand what is happening in ur code):

```
    //hide top logo on load
    var wdwWidth = $(window).width();
    if (wdwWidth <= 991) {
            $("#header-top-logo").css("display", "block");
    } else {
            $("#header-top-logo").css("display", "none");
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't help at all.

Comment: @raqulka what do you mean? Does the #header-top-logo content still show when the address field goes away? If so your if statement does not work.. If there is a gap between the top of your screen and your navbar when the adress field disappears but no #header-top-logo content showing then there is something with your screensize or perhaps body that is wrong.

Comment: @oluf the header logo is gone so the if statement is working. Like I wrote in the question it works perfectly fine on desktop, but on mobile as soon as the address bar disappears, the navbar moves down 50px so it leaves a gap. and then when i scroll again, navbar goes back to the top. I dont know what is causing this.

Comment: @raqulka why involve the .scroll cant you just display and don't display the header?

Comment: @olaf well the header needs to be hidden while scrolling and only be shown while user is on the top

Comment: @raqulka Ok, hmm. when the address field is sliding up on mobile, is the whole header showing or just the part where the address-field were?